# Android: Check & Uncheck Switch Button Through DataBinding with LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, button, android-databinding

I'm currently trying to use databinding to set the check state of my Switch button, but for some reason my state never changes?

In my settings page, I do the following:

1. Check a switch to true
2. Post value to my livedata variable
3. Exit Settings page
4. Re-enter Settings
5. The Switch should be checked because in my XML i bind to it but it is false.

**Files** - **SettingsFragment** - **SettingsViewModel** - **SettingsLayout.XML**

**SettingsViewModel**

```
    private val _checked = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val checked : LiveData<Boolean> = _checked
```

**SettingsLayout.XML**

```
                <Switch
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_big
                android:checked="@{viewModel.checked}"/>
```

I've double checked to make sure that in my **SettingsFragment** I do **DataBindingUtil.inflate** as well and passed my SettingsViewModel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [Two-way data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way) like this:

`android:checked="@={viewModel.checked}"`

Edit: Make sure to add `binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner` in your fragment.

Comment: No luck, hmmmm,

Comment: Make sure you’ve added `binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner` in your fragment.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem! It was the lifecycleowner.